# How to replace re "." in Django template url tag

Tags: django, django-urls

I have Django url routes that looks like this:

```
app_name = 'courses'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'./(?P<courseid>[0-9]+)/$', views.viewcourse, name='view_course'),
  url(r'./(?P<courseid>[0-9]+)/review/$', views.reviewcourse, name='review_course')
]
```

The "." in the regular expression will usually be replaced by a slug, e.g.:

`courses/computer-science/3/`

Now I need a link in my 'view course' template to take the user to the review page, i.e:

`courses/computer-science/3/review/`

I could do this by simply appending `review` to the current url:

`{{ request.path }}review`

However, I would rather do it the 'correct' way using a template url tag

`{% url 'courses:review_course' courseid=course.pk %}`

However, this produces:

`courses/30/review`, which of course fails.

Is it possible to generate the correct link using the {% url %} tag without having to change the "." into a name capture parameter?

Comment: why don't you do ```url(r'(?P<course_type>[a-z_-]+)/(?P<courseid>[0-9]+)/$', views.viewcourse, name='view_course')``` and catch ```course_type``` in your view args to get the good one ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your urls.py :

```
url(r'(?P<course_type>[a-z_-]+)/(?P<courseid>[0-9]+)/$', views.viewcourse, name='view_course')
```

Now in your view you have access to `course_type` in your kwargs and you can then load whatever you want (as I have no code, i'm guessing what you're doing :)).

And in your template:

```
{% url 'courses:review_course' courseid=course.pk course_type=something%}
```

Comment: Would you say this is the 'best practice' way of doing it?

Comment: It's the sane way of doing it

Comment: What's the advantage of using [a-z_-]+ instead of just "." ? The idea is that any string there should work, as long as the courseid is correct.

Comment: well it's actually a string in an url, and url component are letters between a-z (no accent) and _ and -. So i'm just catching the name the proper way.